# Images issue in electron builder

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have created an application using **electron/react js**.
First I have created react app using **create-react-app** then install electron and configure it.
As you know react js does not allow to put images outside **src** folder.
Now when creating build using electron builder application doesn't show images. Images path is broke.
I have included the path in **extraResources**,**extraFiles** in build array but nothing works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.